# read topic without callback

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to read the last message of a topic wihout using a callback? I mean, the tutorials teach to read a topic assigning a callback in a node, so that whenever a topic updates, the callback is executed. I want to read a topic when the user clicks a button, just once, something like this:

> read_topic("/my_topic")

that returns the current data in the topic.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/170361/read-topic-without-callback/) by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-05-27

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get the **next** message in a topic using [ros::topic::waitForMessage()](http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/topic_8h.html).

Note that internally this creates a subscriber on the topic you're interested in, waits for the next message to arrive, and then closes itself down and returns that message to you, so it's a fairly heavy operation, and requires that the topic it's listening to is either a latched topic, or is published frequently.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DNiebuhr](https://answers.ros.org/users/70558/dniebuhr/) on 2021-02-22**:
Do you know if there is an aquivalent in Python?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you're looking for is a [polled topic](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0106.html) which was proposed a while ago, but unfortunately there is currently no plan for it to be implemented.

You can get the same effect by having a variable that gets updated with the most recent message on the topic every time the callback is called, and then read that variable whenever you need the topic.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-05-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2