# Read topic message from subscription without executing callback

Tags: ros2, callback, subscribe, thread

"Reading data from subscription without executing callback" is considered to be one of the common use cases of ROS 2. However, I wonder why there is less description about this use case in any documents about ROS 2.

Many users would like to read data directly from a subscription without executing a callback function.
Executing the callback function, including waking-up and sleeping the thread, consumes CPU time. If the software is small, the consumption is negligible; otherwise, it is not negligible. To reduce unnecessary callback execution in a large software as much as possible, I want to execute callback functions at the time I intend rather than whenever a topic message arrives.

---

I found how to read data with no callback execution, and I would like to give a sample code to demonstrate it. The following source code is based on `demo_nodes_cpp`'s [listener node](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/rolling/demo_nodes_cpp/src/topics/listener.cpp).

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "rclcpp_components/register_node_macro.hpp"

#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;


#include "demo_nodes_cpp/visibility_control.h"

namespace demo_nodes_cpp
{
// Create a TimerListener class that subclasses the generic rclcpp::Node base class.
// The main function below will instantiate the class as a ROS node.
class TimerListener : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  DEMO_NODES_CPP_PUBLIC
  explicit TimerListener(const rclcpp::NodeOptions & options)
  : Node("Timerlistener", options)
  {
    // Create a callback function for when messages are received.
    // Variations of this function also exist using, for example UniquePtr for zero-copy transport.
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);
    auto not_executed_callback =
      [this](std_msgs::msg::String::ConstSharedPtr msg) -> void
      {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I never heard message");
      };
    auto timer_callback =
        [this]() -> void
    {
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Timer triggered.");
      std_msgs::msg::String msg;
      rclcpp::MessageInfo msg_info;
      if (sub_->take(msg, msg_info)) {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Catch message");
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: [%s]", msg.data.c_str());
      } else {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Not catch message");
      }
    };
    // Create a subscription to the topic which can be matched with one or more compatible ROS
    // publishers.
    // Note that not all publishers on the same topic with the same type will be compatible:
    // they must have compatible Quality of Service policies.

    rclcpp::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr cb_group_noexec = this->create_callback_group(
        rclcpp::CallbackGroupType::MutuallyExclusive, false);
    auto subscription_options = rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions();
    subscription_options.callback_group = cb_group_noexec;

    sub_ = create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>("chatter", 10, not_executed_callback, subscription_options);
    timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(500ms, timer_callback);
  }

private:
  rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr sub_;
  rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;

};

}  // namespace demo_nodes_cpp

RCLCPP_COMPONENTS_REGISTER_NODE(demo_nodes_cpp::TimerListener)
```

In the sample program, the `sub_->take()` method is called in `timer_callback` to read data directly from a subscription. The `not_executed_callback` belongs to the callback group whose `automatically_add_to_executor_with_node` is `false` not to execute callback registered with `create_subscription`.

Based on my understanding, I would like to ask two questions.

1. Why is "reading data from subscription without executing callback" hardly mentioned? Is it not recommended?
2. Is there any other best practice of "Reading data from subscription without executing callback" instead of the one I gave?

Thank you for kind cooperation beforehand and best regards,

Please find the similar questions for your reference.

- [Read data from ROS2 topic when I want to instead of callback](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/102622/read-data-from-ros2-topic-when-i-want-to-instead-of-callback)
- [read topic without callback](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/59655/read-topic-without-callback)